# Is there an alternate to TemplatePartAttribute in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

It took me a bit of time to discover this, but designer-specific attributes like `TemplatePart` are now causing issues with the release build of my UWP application.

Applying this attribute to your controls is using reflection.

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PART_Panel, Type = typeof(Panel))]
public class MyAwesomeControl : Control
{
   ...
}
```

And build output gives me this:

> warning : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Panel' was not included in
>   compilation, but was referenced in type 'MyAwesomeControl'. There may
>   have been a missing assembly.

If you want the build to work, I have to exclude that attribute. However, that defeats the purpose of a control library. Users of my library will not know that a `Panel` with the name `PART_Panel` is required in the template of MyAwesomeControl.

Is there a solution to this? Do I have to enable reflection for that type just to allow design-time attributes through?

I am aware of the `rd.xml` file that can be embedded in a project. However, if a `<Type Name="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Panel" ... />` is included, doesn't that mean that I'm telling the compiler to exclude that panel from .Net Native optimization?

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/05/23/net-native-deep-dive-making-your-library-great.aspx) may provide a clue. It was written for VS2013 (.Net Native Beta), so I don't know if it translates to VS2015. Basically the solution is to create an rd.xml file that includes the reflected types in your library. The rd.xml file is built as an embedded resource in your binary so that the end user does not need to do anything.

Comment: Hi @chuex, I've read that article before, and yes it's helpful. However, doesn't that mean that I would tell the compiler to exclude panel from .Net Native optimization?

Comment: I think you've reached the limit of my expertise on this one. The build output above is just a warning... it shouldn't stop you from building, correct? I did try to create a repro project with the template attribute above. I got the warning, but my project still ran ok. Like I said I'm not familiar enough with Blend and designer attributes, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an unfortunate bug in the version of the .Net Native tools (ilc.exe) that you're running on. This attribute is supported properly as of the Update 1 release of Visual Studio. You can get the RC here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

You can safely ignore that warning if you're stuck using older tools.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll investigate this update and get back to you. Glad to hear it's been sorted.

Comment: Yep. Let me know if that doesn't work out (I work on the .Net Natie team :-) )

Comment: Is that right? Anyway we can connect outside of SO? I work for Drawboard, which is a featured app on all the Surfaces. Would love to connect with the technical folks in your department.

Comment: Try mailing dotnetnative at microsoft. You'll find me there.